# EqualityComparer and Action

Tags: c#, wpf, properties

I am using a method to compare two values within my project.

```
public static bool Compare<T>(T x, T y)
{
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y);
}
```

I also have a method for setting a property within my project.

```
protected bool SetField<T>(Action<T> property, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    property(value);
    RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    return true;
}
```

When I try to compare the current value of the property in `Action<T> property` and the `T value` using something like this

```
if (Compare(property, value))
{
    return false;
}
```

I get an error.

> The type arguments for method 'NotifyPropertyChange.Compare(T, T)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I image this is because `property` is an Action.

Is it possible to derive the value of property so it can be used with the `Compare` method?

---

Example usage

```
public int Prop {
    get => model.Prop;
    set => SetField(x => model.Prop = x, value);
}
```

Comment: The only way I see is to pass your old value into your method and compare the oldvalue with the newvalue. I dont see a way how you could read that information, with the given information. (you could get the old value with reflection - `this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null)`)

Comment: @RandRandom Thanks for the comment. That is the method I am currently taking to act as a bypass, I'm just passing in the old value as an extra variable. I was just wondering if there was a simple way to derive it from the action instead

Comment: That's kinda confusing: Action<T> accepts T and returns void, effectively when you provide it with value - the parameter will be value (no obvious reason to compare).

Comment: @Dimitar Hi Dimitar, I have added a example usage in so hopefully it makes a bit more sense. The reason I would like to compare the old value to the new value is so that when updating the value, if they are the same, I do not unnecessarily fire RaisePropertyChanged

Comment: @Dimitar - the his action parameter will probably be implemented like this: `public string Foo { get { return _foo; } set { SetField((x) => _foo = x, value}}` - with this the `value` or the setter will be passed into his method and the `lambda` expression will be called with value which than calls `_foo = x` - so he desires to compare the passed `value` with the old value of `_foo` - I imagine

Comment: What you could do is change your method to `protected bool SetField<T>(ref T oldValue, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null){ if (Compare(oldValue, newValue)) return false; oldValue = newValue; RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName); return true;  }` - so pass your `oldValue` as a `ref` and change its value.

Comment: @RandRandom That works great for a field but unfortunately in C# you can not `ref x.Property`.

Comment: Another option is to change it to a `Func<T, T>` that will set the passed in new value and return the previous old value.  You'd use it like `var oldValue = property(value);`  And call it with `x = > { var t = model.Prop; model.Prop = x; return t; }`.

Comment: Looks too complicated, when you can just compare model.Prop's value with the value in the setter and take actions according to the result. Not to mention thread safety of model.Prop (which looks like a public property).